# Display Recurring Events in Search Result Webparts

Tags: content-search-web-part, recurring-events

I need to show results from an Event List In Content Search Web part, including recurring events.

The iissue is that I am not able to retrieve the recurrent events.

Remark: I know this can be achieved by "SOAP" in CQWP and CEWP but I have  a requirement to do it with Content Search webpart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my research (if this hasn't changed) only the first occurence of a recurring event is indexed by the search engine. The following events are not indexed and hence you can not use a pure Content by Search Webpart approach to accomplish this

Comment: so  Can we Do any thing with Display Template like using SOAP  can we achieve this  or else any method  for particular search

Comment: As far as I know you will not be able to identify recurring events from the search results, but if you are able to do that then you can use JavaScript in a display template to fetch and expand the actual event item. You would have a huge problem with identifying which recurring events that do take place in your current time span though!